# WP7 background audio agent playstate

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, audio, agent

I read the [instructions here about WP7 background audio player agent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/10/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-2.aspx). I thought there is only 1 Unknown event and 1 Playing event in agent side

However, when I log the event in `OnPlayStateChanged` of the agent, using

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(player.PlayerState.ToString();
```

I receive 2 Unknown and 3 Playing events when a new track is play

It's weird, why is that?

P/S: I use the code sample on MSDN [How to: Play Background Audio for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: I fixed it. Take care. You should use playState, not player.PlayState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Torr, I found the reason

> Due to the asynchronous nature of media playback, you should use the
>   arguments to the OnPlayStateChanged callback to drive your logic. You
>   shouldn’t need to query the player (that is mostly for the foreground
>   app to display UI).